# Equation for the orthocenter with complex numbers

Tags: geometry, reference-request, complex-numbers

Did some testing with a CAS and found  this cute fact:

> Consider three points $a$, $b$, $c$ in the complex plane, and $d$ the orthocenter of the triangle $a b c$. Then:
> $$\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & a^2 & \overline a \\
> 1& b & b^2 & \overline b \\
> 1& c & c^2 & \overline c\\
> 1& d & d^2 & \overline d
> \end{pmatrix}=0$$
> The above as an equation in $d$ has $4$ roots: $a$, $b$, $c$ and the orthocenter of $abc$.

Provided as [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Perhaps a known fact, haven't seen it.  References and/or feedback would be appreciated.

Note:

The [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141830/how-to-find-the-center-of-the-circle-that-contains-three-given-complex-numbers/4744438#4744438) for the center of the circle through $abc$ seems relevant. One can obtain from it a formula for the orthocenter.

$\bf{Added:}$ The $\Re$ and $\Im$ of the above equation give rectangular hyperbolas ( see  also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_system#Further_properties)), which pass through the orthocentric system $abcd$.

$\bf{Added:}$

The solution of @Jean Marie: inspired me to get another one a bit more algebraic.  The main idea is still this: since the equation is invariant under complex affine transformations $z \mapsto \alpha z + \beta$, we may assume that $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$ ( the circuscribed circle is the unit circle). Recall that we always have the vector equality ( [Sylvester theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_triangle_problem))

$$\vec{OH}= \vec{OA}+\vec{OB} + \vec{OC}$$

where $O$ is the center of the circuscribed circle of the $\Delta ABC$, and $H$ is the orthocenter.

In our case, since $o = 0$, we get for $d$ the orthocenter ( its complex coordinate)

$$d = a+b+c$$

Recall that $\bar a = \frac{1}{a}$, $\bar b = \frac{1}{b}$ and $\bar c= \frac{1}{c}$, so $\bar d = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c}$

It is enough to show that

Now we need to show that

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{p} &1& p& p^2\\
\frac{1}{q} &1& q& q^2\\
\frac{1}{r} &1& r& r^2 \\
t           &1& s& s^2
\end{pmatrix}=0$$

if $s= p+q+r$, and $t= \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}$. Now there is a vector perpendicular to the first $3$ rows of the above matrix, it is $(-p q r, p q + q r + p r, -(p+q+r), 1)$. We only need to check that it is also orthogonal to the last row, that is

$$\left(-p q r, p q + q r + p r, -(p+q+r), 1\right)\cdot\left( (\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}), 1, (p+q+r), (p+q+r)^2\right) = 0$$

The last two products cancel out obviously, and so do the first two ones.

Comment: Interesting "cousin results" [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/ASUO/mathematics_/vol22-2/Anghel_N..pdf).

Comment: @Jean Marie: Very interesting. Thanks!

Comment: You may also enjoy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think worth of presenting the following approach, though its result is only partialy established (confirmed by numerical computations).

Let us assume WLOG that $a,b,c$ belong to the unit circle.

Your result is equivalent to find a non-zero vector in the kernel of the following matrix (I have transposed it because it was more convenient for me, and exchanged two rows, also WLOG) :

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
a& b & c & d \\
\overline a & \overline b & \overline c & \overline d\\
a^2& b^2 & c^2 & d^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

(or, said differently, an eigenvector associated to eigenvalue $0$).

This eigenvector is :

$$V=\pmatrix{\tan(A)\\ \tan(B) \\ \tan(C) \\ -(\tan(A)+\tan(B)+\tan(C))}$$

The fact that $MV=0$ doesn't really looks like the rabbit out of the hat. Indeed $(\tan(A),\tan(B),\tan(C))$ are, normalized by dividing by their sum, the barycentric coordinates of the orthocenter, explaining the zero products of the 3 first lines of matrix $M$ with $V$.

The surprize comes from the zero product of the 4th line of the matrix with vector $V$ ; I have verified on different numerical examples that it was OK also for this fourth line, but I haven't found a theoretical reason till now...

Here is the Matlab program I have built :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
 t=0:0.01:2*pi;
 p=[0,2*pi/3,5*pi/4,2*pi]; % polar angles
 v=exp(i*p(1:3)); % vertices
 a=v(1);b=v(2);c=v(3);
 A=(p(3)-p(2))/2;
 B=(p(4)-p(3))/2;
 C=(p(2)-p(1))/2;
 an=[A,B,C]; % list of angles
 TL=tan(an); % their tangents
 s=sum(TL);
 d=exp(i*p(1:3))*TL'/s; % orthocenter
 %tri=exp(i*p);plot(tri),hold on;
 %plot(exp(i*t));hold on;
 %plot(d,'or');hold on;
 [TL,-s]*[1 a a^2 conj(a);
          1 b b^2 conj(b);
          1 c c^2 conj(c);
          1 d d^2 conj(d)], % result always equal to (0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: I am asking myself if the answer isn't in lemma 2 of this [document](https://blog.evanchen.cc/2018/02/28/revisiting-arc-midpoints-in-complex-numbers/) saying that "the incenter is the orthocenter of opposite arcs midpoints"

Comment: now I see that the equation is invariant under complex affine maps ( as it should)  so indeed we may assume $a$, $b$, $c$ of norm $1$.

Comment: Wrote another answer based on your idea  to consider $a$, $b$, $c$ of modulus $1$. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The equation is invariant under affine transformations $z\mapsto \alpha z + \beta$. So we may assume that we have an orthocentric system formed by the centers of incircle and excircles of a triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. Let the complex coordinates of the vertices be $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ ( $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$).
Then ([see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845563/formula-for-centers-of-incircle-and-excircles) )the have the orthocentric system formed by

$$-a b - b c - c a\\ 
a b - b c + c a\\
a b + b c - c a\\
- a b + b c + c a$$

and we must show that

$$\det \left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & a b + b c + c a &  (a b + b c + c a)^2 & \frac{1}{a b} + \frac{1}{b c} + \frac{1}{c a} \\
1 & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots  
\end{matrix} \right) = 0$$

Now it is enough to see that each row $0$ dot product with the row $$(a^2 b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2, 0, -1, 2 a^2 b^2 c^2)$$

(so column $3$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $4$).