# Formula for centers of incircle and excircles

Tags: geometry, reference-request, complex-numbers

Was trying to understand a hint of @Jean Marie to a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844195/equation-for-the-orthocenter-with-complex-numbers) about [orthocentric systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_system).  It has to do with the fact [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles)
"the center of the incircle together with the three excircle centers form an orthocentric system".  Therefore, it would be enough to prove it for such systems. Now we need a formula for these centers.  I pulled one out of a classic text of complex numbers in plane geometry. It seems there was a problem with the sign, so I will let the readers decide if it is correct now. The statement is:

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be complex numbers of equal absolute value. Then the center of the inscribed and exinscribed circles have the complex coordinates
> $$-(\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a}\sqrt{c} + \sqrt{b}\sqrt{c})$$

Note that each complex square root has two values $\pm$. However the above expression has in fact $4$ values, as it should.

(Note that this implies

$$\sum_{k=0}^3 \vec{OI_k}=0$$
also
$$\vec{EA}+\vec{EB}+\vec{EC}+\vec{EH}=0$$
where $O$ is the center of the circumscribed circle of a triangle $\Delta ABC$, $H$ is the orthocenter, and $E$ is the center of the nine-point circle.   Known, but new to me).

I could not find it in other sources, but certainly it is known, so it is stated as a [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are of equal value, they are the same. Does this mean they are of equal *absolute* value?

Comment: Isn't the last equality the same as the problem of Sylvester? See formulas here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Orthocenter

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: the consequences are nothing new, if that is the question, they were only new to me

Comment: @R. J. Mathar: Thank you, yes! corrected now

Comment: Do you mean circumcircles?  I know those formulas for real numbers for triangle lengths.

Comment: @John: Well, it is about the centers of incircle and [excircles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles)